# Existence of a positive semidefinite matrix that satisfies a set of equality constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, positive-semidefinite, semidefinite-programming

Given vectors $a_1, b_2, a_2, b_2 \in \mathcal{R}^{n\times 1}$, I am interested in finding a positive semi-definite matrix $M \in \mathcal{R}^{n\times n}$, $M \succeq 0$, such that $M\cdot a_1 = b_1$, $M\cdot a_2 = b_2$. Here $n \gg 2$, say $n = 1000 $. $a_1, a_2$ are not parallel and are non-zero.

To write it in equations, I want to solve the following semidefinite program

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{M}{\text{minimize}}
& & 0 \\
& \text{subject to}
& & M\cdot a_1 = b_1 \\
&& & M\cdot a_2 = b_2 \\
&&& M \succeq 0.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Depending on the value of $a_1, b_2, a_2, b_2$, sometimes a numerical solver will report this program is infeasible (no such $M$ exists). I have experimented with multiple solvers with identical result. I can further impose that $a_1^T\cdot b_1>0, a_2^T\cdot b_2>0$, but the result is the same.

An observation: If $a_1, a_2$ are orthogonal, it appears the problem is always feasible.

My intuition is that the number of free variables in $M$ is $(n(n+1)/2 -n)$, because a symmetric matrix has $n(n+1)/2$ free variables, and positive semidefiniteness requires all principal minors to be positive, adding $n$ constraints. It appears this intuition is not correct.

What is the requirement of $a_1, b_2, a_2, b_2$ for $M$ to exist?

Comment: @Rahul, thanks so much for your comments. I will try your approach. I am curious in this semi-definite program what exactly is the number of free-variables, and how does it depend on $a$ and $b$?

Comment: You need more consistency conditions on $b_1$ and $b_2$. For example, if $a_i = e_i$ is the $i$ Standard Basis vector, then by symmetry of $M$ we have $b_{2,1} = b_{1,2}$.

Comment: You could assume $a_i = e_i$ wlog. It probably won’t make the problem easier. Have you check the bfgs update technique? Not sure if it helps.

Comment: @user251257  Thanks so much for your comment. I just checked bfgs as you suggested. However bfgs only satisfies one and only one constraint, here I could potentially have many such constraints. Also can you elaborate what is $b_{2,1}$ and $b_{1,2}$ in your previous comment?

Answer (score 2):

One way to look at this is to derive the dual, and determine the conditions under which the dual is unbounded---because that means the original problem is infeasible.

The Lagrangian is
$$L(M,Z,\lambda_1,\lambda_2) = \lambda_1^T(M a_1-b_1)+\lambda_2^T(M a_2-b_2) - \langle M, Z \rangle$$
Where the scalar Lagrange multipliers $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ are unconstrained and $Z$ is positive semidefinite. So the dual optimality condition is
$$\mathop{\textrm{sym}}(a_1 \lambda_1^T + a_2 \lambda_2^T) - Z = 0$$
where $\mathop{\textrm{sym}}(Y)=(Y+Y^T)/2$, and the dual problem is
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{maximize} & - b_1^T \lambda_1 - b_2^T \lambda_2 \\
\text{subject to} & \mathop{\textrm{sym}}(a_1 \lambda_1^T + a_2 \lambda_2^T) - Z = 0 \\
& Z \succeq 0
\end{array}
Eliminating $Z$ yields
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{maximize} & - b_1^T \lambda_1 - b_2^T \lambda_2 \\
\text{subject to} & \mathop{\textrm{sym}}(a_1 \lambda_1^T + a_2 \lambda_2^T) \succeq 0 \\
\end{array}
And we see that this is unbounded if there exists $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ such that
$$\mathop{\textrm{sym}}(a_1 \lambda_1^T + a_2 \lambda_2^T) \succeq 0, \quad b_1^T \lambda_1 + b_2^T \lambda_2 < 0$$
If you can find even one pair that satisfies these inequalities, then you can just scale
$(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$ by any positive value to drive the dual objective to infinity. And if you can do that, the primal must be infeasible. Since the scaling is irrelevant, we can easily fix it at $b_1^T \lambda_1 + b_2^T \lambda_2 = -1$.

The formal name for this exercise is the derivation of a *theorem of alternatives*. That is, exactly one of the following alternatives is true [EDIT: see the comments, neither may be true]: either
$$\exists M \succeq 0 \quad \text{s.t.} \quad Ma_1 = b_1,  ~ Ma_2 = b_2$$
or
$$\exists \lambda_1, \lambda_2 \quad\text{s.t.} \quad \mathop{\textrm{sym}}(a_1 \lambda_1^T + a_2 \lambda_2^T) \succeq 0, \quad b_1^T \lambda_1 + b_2^T \lambda_2 = -1$$

Comment: since $Z$ is a matrix, how is $\lambda_1 a_1 + \lambda_2 a_2 = Z$ valid? Did you mean $<\lambda_1,a_1> + <\lambda_1,a_2> = tr\{Z\}$ where $<.,.>$ is the appropriate dot-product.. or am I missing something

Comment: You're not missing anything---I misinterpreted the dimensions

Comment: Corrected. Thanks @dineshdileep. Alas, it's not nearly as interesting corrected ;-)

Comment: I keep forgetting, is the infeasibility of the primal and the unboundedness of the dual an if-and-only-if?

Comment: Not always. It is possible for both primal and dual to be infeasible, or for there to be a nonzero duality gap. Good point, this may mean this is not in fact a true theorem of alternatives. We can say _no more_ than one of the alternatives is true, but not _exactly_ one.